# The Ul LI causing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, html-lists, horizontal-scrolling

I am using UL and LI elements for making a tree. The tree can be have n level. To make UL Li to look like a tree I am using following CSS:

```
.TreeView
{
    font: Verdana;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: normal;
}

.TreeView LI
{
    /* The padding is for the tree view nodes */
    padding: 0 0 0 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none; 
}

.TreeView, .TreeView ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And the HTML is

```
<ul class="TreeView">
   <li>some text
     <ul class="TreeView">
          <li>some text
            <ul class="TreeView">
              <li>some text
                      ..... this can be n level
              </li>  
            </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
     </li>  
 </ul>
```

In above structure all LI's will have 20px padding from left so when the level increases it will lead to horizontal scroll.

How can I avoid the horizontal scroll?

Comment: As per my remark on your other post, please do not revert edits unless the new form of the question is contrary to the purpose of the post. It is quite normal for chatty posts to be cleaned up here. If you disagree with my edit, please ping me on every post where you disagree, so I can involve a moderator. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

for li element as;

```
.TreeView LI
{
/* The padding is for the tree view nodes */
padding: 0 0 0 18px;
float: left;
width: 100%;
list-style: none; 
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qfQ53/2/

Comment: Yeah.. it's working in both IE in chrome. I was wonder about the IE as you placed the css for web-kit browsers but anyway it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, and it's good luck for me as I am not allowing IE <= 8. Thanks BRO for the general and short and sweet answer :)..

Comment: Glad to have helped. You can use -mox-box-sizing:border-box for Firefox ≤ 28 http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can try removing the width and float attributes and adding this to your ul css

```
overflow: hidden;
```

please report back the changes that happen when you do so or even better create a JFiddle if you can.

Comment: It will hide all the scroll bars.. and I don't think it's a general solution?

Comment: @nrsharma it will only hide the scrollbars in that particular ul. It should work fine, what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

to hide only the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: It will hide horizontal scroll bars.. and I don't think it's a general solution?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/J8x4H/)**</kbd>

Remove `padding` from `.TreeView LI`

You can use `list-style` as

```
ul {
    list-style: <list-style-type> || <list-style-position> || <list-style-image>;
}
```

You need `list-style-position : outside` as below

```
ul {
    list-style:decimal outside none;
}
```

You final CSS

```
.TreeView {
    font: Verdana;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: normal;
}
.TreeView LI {
    /* The padding is for the tree view nodes */
    /*padding: 0 0 0 18px;*/
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
ul {
    list-style:decimal outside none;
}
```

Example HTML with added `ul` `li`

```
<ul class="TreeView">
    <li>some text
        <ul class="TreeView">
            <li>some text
                <ul class="TreeView">
                    <li>some text
                        <ul class="TreeView">
                            <li>some text
                                <ul class="TreeView">
                                    <li>some text
                                        <ul class="TreeView">
                                                <li>some text
                                                    <ul class="TreeView">
                                                        <li>some text ..... this can be n level</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/J8x4H/1/)**</kbd>

For giving a variable padding

```
ul {
    list-style:decimal outside none;
    padding: 0 0 0 18px
}
```

[**Read here for more details**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/)

Comment: It will add an constant padding for the li elements.. I don't want that. But thanks for the answer..

Comment: If you add `padding: 0 0 0 18px;` thats too a constant padding? What exactly you wish it to behave ?

Comment: The padding can be vary, but in your example there isn't any count for that. Anyway your answer is also useful :)

Comment: Okies, I made an edit to the answer. You can follow you there.